# Testing for continuity over a given domain

Tags: functions

Is there any way to use *Mathematica* to test whether a function is continuous over a given domain?

Comment: Maple has [iscont](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=iscont).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely to be very slow..

```
isDiscontinuous[f_, low_, high_] := 
 Resolve[Exists[del, del > 0, ForAll[eps, eps > 0,
    Exists[{x1, x2}, 
     low <= x1 < x2 <= high && x2 - x1 < eps && 
      Abs[f[x1] - f[x2]] > del]]]]
```

Here are simple examples.

```
ff[x_] := x^2 + x

isDiscontinuous[ff, -1, 2]

(* Out[334]= False *)

gg[x_] := Sign[x]

Resolve[isDiscontinuous[gg, -1, 2]]

(* Out[331]= True *)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for the `Sin[x]/x` example.

Comment: @george2079 My guess is the underlying engine in the quantifier elimination is not happy with non-rational functions.

Answer (score 5):

We can call Wolfram|Alpha then use `Reduce`.

Let's say you want the discontinuities of `Sin[x]/x + 1/(x-2)` for `-1 < x < 1`.

First find all discontinuities:

```
all = ReleaseHold[WolframAlpha["discontinuities of Sin[x]/x + 1/(x-2)", {{"Result", 1}, "Output"}]]
(* x == 0 || x == 2 *)
```

then find the values in your domain:

```
Reduce[all && -1 < x < 1, x, Reals]
(* x == 0 *)
```

Pack this into a function:

```
Discontinuities[f_, x_, domain_:True] := Module[{str, all},

  str = ToString[f, InputForm];
  all = ReleaseHold[WolframAlpha["discontinuities of " <> str, {{"Result", 1}, "Output"}]];

  If[MatchQ[all, _Missing], Return[False]];

  Reduce[all && domain, x, Reals]
]

Discontinuities[Sin[x]/x + 1/(x-2), x, -1 < x < 1]
(* x == 0 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can readily catch "some" discontinuities like this:

```
 Reduce[ Denominator[Together[ Sin[x]/x  + 1/(x - 2)]] == 0 ]
```

> x == 0 || x == 2

Likely WolframAlpha applies a suite of such tests.