# Determining the order of continuity (smoothness) of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, code-request

**Is there any method to determine the [order of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Order_of_continuity) of a function (just like an interpolant) over a given domain, or at least determine the continuity on a given order?**

For example, according to references the [cubic hermite interpolant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) `3t^2 - 2t^3` is C1, since it's first derivative is contiuous.
How can I determine the same result or say, the order of continuity of cosine interpolant `(1 - Cos[t * Pi]) / 2`?

Comment: Is this question about *Mathematica*, or about the mathematical problem itself? I.e. do you have a procedure in mind that you want to implement in *Mathematica* code (appropriate here), or do you want help in finding such a procedure (more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It's about Wolfram Mathematica, since it's Mathematica stackexchange.

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47965/1063) will be of help.